# Team foundation error Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, assemblies

I am trying to edit the build definition of one of my builds on Visual Studio (specifically, changing the password). As soon as I am finished and press Ctrl+S I get the following error:

Team Foundation Error

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf2856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have looked into my build, dev and production servers and I can see the file and it is the correct version (5.0.414.0). Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Just to clarify, you get this error when you save the updated build definition in VS on your local machine? You're not editing the xaml or seeing the error when the build is running?

Comment: Yes, I was getting the error when saving the updated build definition in Visual Studio on my machine. It was a Visual Studio issue- a solved it an hour after my post. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue entirely with Visual Studio on my local machine, not TFS.

Apparently when you edit a build definition, Team Explorer 2010 assumes you're doing it for your currently open solution. I still do not know why it could not find the assembly when it was clearly in my bin\Debug directory, but there you go.

The solution was a simple closing and re-opening Visual Studio. I was then able to edit and save the definition with the new parameter and promote to production appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the assembly is included in your project and if it exist in the folder of your solution.

Sometimes when a person do a "Check In", but just some files the project dont know that the assembly must be included.

hope it helps.